# WSO2 Integrator: HTTP Status 401 - how to get the error body?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We are using the latest available **WSO2 Integrator v. 6.6.0**.

I am calling a HTTP endpoint (REST API) from my sequence, and depending on the content of my message, the endpoint will respond either with HTTP 200 OK with a JSON response body, or **HTTP 401 Unauthorized (also with a JSON response body - an error body detailing the problem)**.

For example:

```
{
    "error_reason": "Invalid identifier",
    "error_description": "You do not have access to the specified identifier",
    "http_status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I need to access the **error_description** field of the returned error to return it to the original sender of the message in my sequence.

**How can I do this using WSO2 Integrator?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter mediator to check the HTTP Status code and write the logic. You can find a sample below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mocky" name="Mocky" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="GET" uri-template="https://run.mocky.io/v3/570d617a-0b39-4ca1-b209-60d4b9abadb5">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <filter regex="401" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
                <then>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{"message" :  "$1"}</format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.error_description"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <respond/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{"message" :  "Happy Path"}</format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <respond/>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: This suggestion does not work because my POST call results in HTTP status 401 and therefore it ends up in the fault sequence, and never reaches the filter as described above
I am using call blocking=true because i need to have a long timeout
In the fault sequence, the error body is also not present, it just shows the original POST message body that I sent out, and the error body.

Comment: @PetteriPertola were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing a similar problem and would appreciate any solutions/workarounds to achieve this.

Comment: Yes - there was a way around this, but I can't remember how we solved it and I don't have access to the code anymore as I changed workplaces :( But if I recall right, it was very 'hacky/messy' solution as everything tends to be with WSO2, so we also started a project to replace WSO2 with a number of Spring Boot microservices written in Java instead. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and then use filter to get payload and status code . This property won't take it to fault sequence.

```html
<property name="non.error.http.status.codes" value="403" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

Ref: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/http-transport-properties/